# int cannot be dereferenced compilation error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting an error when I try to compile this code saying

> int cannot be dereferenced

What could be causing it?  Here is this code I am using:

```
class A {

    public static void main(String str[]) {

        int System=22;      
        System.out.println(System);
    }

}
```

Comment: System is keyword in java ...

Comment: You should add the language you are using (Java?) to the tags.

Comment: @vinod - `System` isn't a keyword, but it's a class in the `java.lang` package that's imported into all Java programs by default.  By declaring `System` to be an `int` the OP blocked the definition of it as a class and hence `.out` appeared to be an attempt to reference a data member of an `int`, not something you can do.

Comment: And standard Java coding convention is to reserve symbols with leading upper-case letters for class names.  A variable name should begin with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 1):

By writing

```
int System = 22;
```

you are hiding the class [java.lang.System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html). So when you try to do

```
System.out.println(...
```

the compiler thinks you want to have access the varilable `out` of an `int` which it doesn't have as it is a primitive type.

You could write

```
int system = 22;
System.out.println(system);
```

Variable names should start with lowercase anyways.

Comment: Thanks everyone for there valuable answers specially@ A4L. I got this question while solving sample papers for OCJP and i knew it would throw an error but wasn't sure of exactly why.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use language specific keywords for your variable names. Change the name of the variable 'System' and it should work fine.

Comment: It's not a keyword.  Had it been a keyword, the compiler would have objected.